# How to make an excel stacked bar chart with average value?

Tags: excel

I have the following excel data :
[excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp0vp.png)

i need to have a vertical stacked bar chart showing for PC1/interface and PC2/interface the average amount per type.
I have tried to add a column with average for each type but i don't know how to use it in a chart.

Thanks

Comment: create a pivot table with pivotchart and use the Average aggregate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pivotchart and pivotable and set the aggregate function for the data field to average. Arrange fields as as required so you stack the items of interest.

Set-up with dummy data:

[image: Setup]
Result

[image: Result]